# Update a rendered component props

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

Can I update a **React** component's props such as a **className** due to an event like a click? It seems impossible since the component is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can.

create a state and keep className:

```js
const [elmClass, setElmClass] = React.useState("first");
```

use className and update it onClick:

```js
<div className={elmClass} onClick={() => {setElmClass("second")}>
  Change my className
</div>
```

take a look at this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-bash-bcfx7